# Uploading a self-signed certificate for Telegram Bot

Tags: telegram-bot

I have a Self-signed certificate on the server where the bot is located.

The bot is written in Django, I send the following request

`curl-F "url=http:/ / promauto. ru/telegram/bot/" - F "certificate=@YOURPUBLIC.pem" "https://api.telegram.org/bot/setWebhook"`

the response in the curl console is: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function could not perform a revocation check for the certificate. What am I doing wrong?